# Invalid MEX-file: Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib

Tags: matlab

macOS Mojave 10.14.5

While trying to run a MEX file in Matlab R2018b I got the following error: 
Invalid MEX-file '/Users/...':
dlopen(/Users/...'): Library not loaded:
@loader_path/libmex.dylib

Reason: image not found.

I've already seen that this is problem related to the Mac's SIP but I can't find out how to solve it.

How can I solve this issue in matlab mac?

Comment: Did you build the MEX-file yourself or did you get a binary from somewhere else? Building it on your system might solve the issue.